# CMD auto-completion not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete

(Python 3.3.4)

I am currently using the cmd module to build an application, but for some reason I just can't get the completion to work correctly. Whenever I hit `tab` it just indents my input string!!

So, if I have something like this:
`(MyShell)>> ta«cursor here»`
I hit «tab» and get this:
`(MyShell)>> ta    «cursor here»`

I have tried in IDLE, the Windows Power Shell and in the Python interpreter itself, I guess...
Neither the completion of commands nor the completion of arguments work!!

The code is this:

```
class MyShell(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.intro = "Welcome to MyShell test.\nPowered by Rodrigo Serrão"
        self.prompt = "(MyShell)>>"

    def do_talk(self, text):
        print("Hello")

    stuff = ["blabla", "bananas!", "noodles"]
    def complete_talk(self, text, line, s, e):
        if text:
            return [i for i in stuff if i.startswith(text)]
        else:
            return stuff


MyShell().cmdloop()
```

I have read some questions about this, including this one:
[Python Cmd Tab Completion Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994424/python-cmd-tab-completion-problems)

And it may have to do with that `readline` thing. I tried to import it, but apparently I don't have it.

Answer (score 5):

if it is a problem of your check this approach.

Go to run and type regedit.

Go to LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor.

And change the **PathCompletionChar** value to 9. Usually it is 40. That means your current auto completion key is *not* the TAB key. After you assign the value 9 close the window and restart the CMD.

Now this would be fixed. Auto completion of paths would be working fine by the TAB key.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm writing a interactive shell app on Python too, to get auto completion working, install **pyreadline**, the **readline** module is Unix specific.

If you don't know how install just execute the following line:

*pip* *install* **pyreadline**

Comment: Didn't work for me. I did 'sudo pip3 install pyreadline'. I'm on Python 3.5.2:

Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

Comment: @battey I tested with a Windows, as you can see PyReadline is specific for it [pyreadline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline/2.1), try this [anyreadline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/anyreadline/0.1.1)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried installing anyreadline, and autocompletion still didn't work.